# Split Columns with delimiter and export to csv

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file that contains data in the below format:

```
Name     Codes
------- ---------
John    AJFKC,EFUY
Ben    EFOID, EIUF
Alex    OIPORE, OUOIJE
```

I would like to get the above in the below format and output it into a new csv file as below:

```
Name     Codes
------- ---------
John    AJFKC
John    EFUY
Ben     EFOID
Ben     EIUF
Alex    OIPORE
Alex    OUOIJE
```

Comment: This site does not write code for you to order, we assist you with a single specific and properly explained issue with your provided code. Please post a [mcve] of your code, and the explanation of how it fails to work as written and intended. Please also take a look at [ask], _including each of its linked pages_ .

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if there will always be 2 codes per name:

```
Import-Csv file.csv | Foreach-Object {
    $codes = ($_.Codes -split ',').Trim()
    [pscustomobject]@{Name = $_.Name; Codes = $codes[0]}
    [pscustomobject]@{Name = $_.Name; Codes = $codes[1]}
}
```

If the number of codes per name is unknown, you can do the following:

```
Import-Csv file.csv | Foreach-Object {
    $codes = ($_.Codes -split ',').Trim()
    foreach ($code in $codes) {
        [pscustomobject]@{Name = $_.Name; Codes = $code}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is how this file really looks, it's not a Csv file. It's just a text file based copying and using what you posted. It's left-justified, vs columns, here the staggered look of it. The file has 5  spaces for that name column between it and that left justified Codes column with a code array.

So, though it looks like a table/tabular format, it's not really that. As in an import that name column would include the first of the code strings, thus cause some issues with your desired output. So, that text file would need to be manipulated a bit more, or who or whatever provides you the file, should make is a legitimate CSV.

So, here's my take on the assumptions in the aforementioned.

```
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\UserRecord.csv') -replace ', ',',' | 
Select -Skip 2 | 
ForEach {
    $Name = (($PSItem) -split '\s+')[0]
    ($PSItem -split '\s+')[1] -split ',' | 
    ForEach {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name  = $Name
            Codes = $PSItem
        }
    }
}    
# Results
<#
Name Codes 
---- ----- 
John AJFKC 
John EFUY  
Ben  EFOID 
Ben  EIUF  
Alex OIPORE
Alex OUOIJE
#>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Import-Csv "c:\temp\test.csv" -Delimiter "`t" | %{
    $Name=$_.Name
    $_.Codes -split "," | %{ [pscustomobject]@{Name=$Name;Code=$_.Trim()}}
}
```